# How to stop card from being click in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am using compound card and showing final details to the user but it is also being clicked, which is leading nowhere and I am not intended to proceed on click. So how to stop that click from being triggered?

```
on-click {
       intent {
             goal: MainChoice
             value-set:MultipleID{$expr(singleId)}
             }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that I am using list-of to list down the answer. So after list-of, all we have to do is make `has-details` key to false. So code will look like this

```
list-of (array) {
      has-details (false)
      where-each (one) {
        compound-card {
           // content
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `on-click` key is optional. Simply omit the code you have defining an `on-click` event and the card will not be clickable.

Comment: I am not using `on-click` key in my layout but still it is getting clicked

Comment: I would suggest that you open a ticket with the support team as this looks like a question where we would need to look at your entire capsule. The best way to file a support ticket would be to open Bixby Studio and select the "Contact Support" options from the Help dropdown menu found in the top navigation bar.